How to send an excel file from Python Bottle backend to Vue JS frontend? Using bottle static_file() results in CORS error
How do I send an excel file saved on the PC running the backend to the frontend browser (accessed from another machine) that requests the file?
I have a python bottle backend that I want to use to send an excel file to the Vue JS frontend to be downloaded by the frontend user.  The excel file is created from a database based on inputs from the user and then when I try to send back the resulting excel file I get a CORS error.
If I send data as a string back it is saved to a downloaded excel but I'm not sure how to move an actual file, saved on the backend PC to the frontend.
Forgetting about generating the file, I am just trying to send one saved excel file from the backend to the front end and I get the following error
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8090/generateExcel. (Reason: CORS header ?Access-Control-Allow-Origin? missing). Status code: 200.
Here is the backend code sending the excel file:
    import json
    from bottle import run, static_file, request, response, Bottle

    class EnableCors(object):
        name = 'enable_cors'
        api = 2

        def apply(self, fn, context):
            def _enable_cors(*args, **kwargs):
                # set CORS headers
                response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
                response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
                response.headers[
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token'
                if context.method != 'OPTIONS':
                    # actual request; reply with the actual response
                    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

            return _enable_cors


    app = Bottle()
    app.install(EnableCors())

    @app.route("/generateExcel", method=["OPTIONS", "POST"])
    def generateExcel():
        print("here")
        
        # This is a local directory and file
        file_dir = "/home/data/excelFiles/"
        file_name = "sample_excel.xlsx"  # file defintely exists!

        return static_file(filename=file_name, root=file_dir)

Here is the front vue js code that calls it
    fetch( process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_ADDR + '/' + 'generateExcel', 
        { 
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, 
            body: JSON.stringify(parameters),
            responseType: 'blob' 
        }
    ).then((response) => {
        console.log("here 2")
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a')
        link.href = url
        link.setAttribute('download', fileName)
        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        let errorResponse = { status: "red", message: error + " in " + endpoint };
        console.log(errorResponse);
    })


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Question has been editted a bit - but what I am trying to do is simply to send a file (not data) from the backend to the frontend - I have put these pieces of code together from reading up on how to send a file via a python bottle server and how to download an excel file through a vue-js frontend - I've not found any examples with those two parts in the one example

Mostly because those parts are totally unrelated so far. What does not work here? Frontend or backend? Isolate the issue.

I don't know which part isn't working but when I try to send send the file I get a CORS error but CORS is enabled - when I just send a string from the backend, there's no error - the string is written to a downloaded excel file saved by the browser (frontend) side - could this be a CORS issue - is there something specific that needs to be set to allow files to be sent or received? - I'll add in my CORS bit to the python code

So I've finally figured out how to do this and there was a number of things going on.  First was the CORS, which was solved by adding to the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'. Second was what I was sending, I should have been sending the content of the file rather than the file.  Finally third was on the frontend and I need to wait for the content before writing to the browser excel file to be downloaded.
Here is the updated and working backend Python bottle code -
from bottle import run, static_file, request, response, Bottle
class EnableCors(object):
    name = 'enable_cors'
    api = 2

    def apply(self, fn, context):
    def _enable_cors(*args, **kwargs):
        # set CORS headers
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
        # had to add 'Content-Disposition' to 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token, Content-Disposition'
        if context.method != 'OPTIONS':
        # actual request; reply with the actual response
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return _enable_cors


app = Bottle()
app.install(EnableCors())

@app.route("/generateExcel", method=["OPTIONS", "POST"])
def generateExcel():
    print("here")
    
    # file_dir is full path to the file, including filename
    file_dir = "/home/data/excelFiles/sample_excel.xlsx"
    file_name = "sample_excel.xlsx"

    # adding specific CORS requirements here
    response.content_type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % file_name

    # need to retunr file content, rather than the file
    with open(file_dir, 'rb') as file:
        return file.read()

Now the updated vue-js code, I created an async function I import from a utilities.js file and I have to await both the fetch response and for the response.blob(), if I don't the resulting downloaded file just has "undefined" in it -
export async function postExcelFileReq(endpoint, parameters, fileName) {
    console.log(endpoint, fileName, parameters);
    const response = await fetch(process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_ADDR + "/" + endpoint, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(parameters) ,
        responseType: 'blob'
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    } else {
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const link = document.createElement('a')
        link.href = url
        link.setAttribute('download', fileName)
        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()

        // clean up after download
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
}

I did use ChatGPT once I had a better understanding of where the problem might be, I know it says no AI answers but this could be very helpful for anyone else struggling to do this.

Just to add I assume, but I've not tested, that this can be used to send different file types by changing response.content_type and downloading to an appropriately name file
